# Java: substring from index to end

Tags: java, string, substring

I've been trying that, but without much success:

```
String whatIShouldSay = "no more beer please!";
String whatIActuallySay = whatIShouldSay.substring(3,-1);
System.out.println (whatIActuallySay);
```

But it doesn't work like that. But why so? What could I do instead?
As a workaround I could do:

```
whatIShouldSay.substring(3,whatIShouldSay.length());
```

But that doesn't feel like an elegant solution to me.
Would be grateful for a hint! :)

P.S.: Would you write "should" in "whatIShouldSay" with a lowercase or with an uppercase "s"?

Comment: There is an other substring method which takes only one parameter, which is the inclusive begin index. The returned string always ends where the original string ends.

Comment: To answer your P.S.: it should is clearly upper case, there's no good reason to not do that. One area where this answer is not quite as clear are abbreviations that are usually written in ALL-CAPS (such as HTTP) which lead to weird names. The [Google Java code style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.3-camel-case) has a nice discussion on the topic of corner cases for camel case.

Answer (score 3):

The [one-argument variant of `substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) will return the string starting from the argument up to the end:

```
String whatIActuallySay = whatIShouldSay.substring(3);
```

Note that the convention of using negative indices to count from the back of some sequence is almost never used in Java (never in the core libraries, as far as I know and very rarely in third-party libraries).